# Convert a .pk8 file to .key file

Tags: android, openssl

I have a .pk8 file and I want to convert it into .key file format,so that I can move them into a pkcs12 store and then later to java keystore using keytool.

Please suggest possible solutions??

Answer (score 10):

Use the OpenSSL command line tool to convert your PKCS#8 file to a plain private key first:

```
openssl pkcs8 -in file.pk8 -out key.pem
```

If that gives you an error it's probably because the key is in DER format, try this then:

```
openssl pkcs8 -in file.pk8 -inform DER -out key.pem
```

Gather the certificates you want to be in your PKCS#12 key store and make sure they are PEM-encoded (open them in a text editor - if the file starts with '----- BEGIN X.509 CERTIFICATE -----' or similar then you're already good to go):

```
openssl x509 -in single_cert.cer -inform DER -out single_cert.pem
```

Open a text editor and paste all the PEM-encoded certificates **plus** the contents of key.pem in that file, one after the other to get a file like this:

```
----- BEGIN RSA PRIVATEKEY ----- '' or another format, depends on your key
...contents of your key file
----- END RSA PRIVATEKEY -----
----- BEGIN X.509 CERTIFICATE -----
...contents of certificate 1
----- END X.509 CERTIFICATE -----
----- BEGIN X.509 CERTIFICATE -----
...contents of certificate 2
----- END X.509 CERTIFICATE -----
...
```

Save this, e.g. as all.pem. To finally create your PKCS#12 key store, issue this command:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in all.pem -out file.p12 -name "somename"
```

Provide a password and your done. The `name` parameter is going to be your "alias" in the Java world.

Comment: I am getting the following error in executing the first pk8 to pem conversion routine . Error -> error reading key expecting encrypted private key...error in pkcs8

Comment: Sounds like the PKCS#8 key is unencrypted - try adding the `-nocrypt` parameter.

Comment: with the 2nd one ie openssl pkcs8 -in file.pk8 -inform DER -out key.pem I am getting the follwoing error Error->Error reading key asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN :wrong tag,ASN1_ITEM_EX_D2I ,ASN1_TEMPLETE_NOEXP_D2I error in pkcs8  Thanks

Comment: Try `openssl pkcs8 -in file.pk8 -nocrypt -out key.pem` or `openssl pkcs8 -in file.pk8 -inform DER -nocrypt -out key.pem`?

Answer (score 2):

Following [this guide](http://jmlinnik.blogspot.fi/2011/12/keystores.html) worked for me. Specifically using [keytool-iui](https://code.google.com/p/keytool-iui/) to import the private key.